# Proxy within a proxy, tunneling?

Tags: proxy, tunnel

At work there is a proxy that (understandably) blocks all ports except web ones.

However, during lunch hours you are allowed to play online games. But as ports are blocked, multiplayer games are out of the question.

So I was wondering, could I set up a tunnel on a web port, that would then allow me to access those blocked ports, through the port 80 tunnel whilst still being behind the work proxy?

This is in a Windows environment.

Answer (score 0):

You could set up a machine as a "server" at home and build an SSH tunnel to it on port 80.  You could also check to see if VPN's are allowed through the proxy/firewall.  If that's the case you could use a VPN server (there are MANY available as a paid service on line).  NONE of this is meant to encourage you to violate any rules in the IT department.  If you need direction in how to create an SSH tunnel [HAK5](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=S-s_rUpz6Eg) has done many articles on it.  If you have any further questions reply and I'll see what I can help you with.